# How to configure/install Amazon S3 on-prem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we configure/install Amazon S3 on-prem? Is there a way to configure Amazon S3 on-prem instead of Amazon. I know there is a `Hybrid cloud storage` type but this will store data on-prem and S3 as-well.

But I am looking for a solution where the S3 should be managed and store data on-prem VPC only.

Comment: No. But the closes you could maybe get for testing and development purposes is [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) but this is not AWS.

Comment: What is your use case please? Development?

Comment: for security reasons we don't want to push files to Amazon S3., But we want to use the S3 as on-prem only.

Comment: Consider minio or other similar object storage projects. I believe minio is S3 API compatible, but there are other options.

Comment: @kichik minio looks very nice. Thanks, didn't know about this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minio https://min.io/ - would give you DIY option for S3 - compatible on-prem storage. Alternatively - if you ready to spend a lot of money and keep your data on-prem with AWS S3 - take a look at [AWS Outpost](https://aws.amazon.com/outposts/)